# Inequality for descents after applying Cauchy-Schwarz

Tags: probability-theory, inequality

Let $S_i$ be the symmetric group defined over i elements. Let $W_i$ be defined as $$W_i=D_i-\frac{i-1}{2}.$$ $D_i$ is the random variable counting the number of descents of a random permutation in $S_i$ (so we know that $E[D_i]=\frac{i-1}{2},$ $\operatorname{Var}(D_i)=\frac{i+1}{12}$ and $E[D_n^3]=\frac{(n^2-n+2)(n-1)}{8}$)

Then one has

\begin{align*}
\frac{144}{n^4(n+1)^2}\left(  \sum_{1\le i, j \le n-1} E[W_{i-1}^2 W_{j-1}^2] \right) &\stackrel{Cauchy}{\le} \frac{144}{n^4(n+1)^2} \left( \sum_{1 \le i, j \le n-1} \sqrt{E[W_{i-1}^4]E[W_{j-1}^4]} \right) \\
&\stackrel{?}{\le} \frac{C}{n^4(n+1)^2} \left( \sum_{1 \le i, j\le n-1}ij \right)
\end{align*}

I'm having problems understanding how to get the inequality that I marked as $?$. While I understand that I can choose a big enough constant instead of $144$, but I don't get how the terms in the root are bounded by $ij$.

Comment: You enter too quickly into your question : number of descends in which kind of sequence ?

Comment: Hi Jean, sorry. Let me rewrite my question

Comment: You may use the fact that $$ \mathbb{E}[W_n^4] = \frac{(5n+3)(n+1)}{240} $$ for $n \geq 4$.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on that ? I had calculated the moment for $D_n^4$, but my results got a bit messy. I had $E[D_n^4]=\frac{n^4}{16}-\frac{n^3}{8}+\frac{13n^2}{48}+ \mathcal{O}(n$)

Comment: My computation is also messy, relying on the expansion $$\mathbb{E}[z^{D_n}]=\frac{A_n(z)}{n!}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(n-k)!}{n!}\left\{{n\atop n-k}\right\}t^{n-k}(1-t)^k$$ where $\bigl\{{k \atop j}\bigr\}$ is the [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).

Comment: Ok. Let me see if I got it correctly; you are using Eulerian numbers when you mean $A_n(z)$ right? If yes, can show me where you got the first equality? $E[z^{D_n}]=\frac{A_n(z)}{n!}$ I might be overthinking things, but I wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Descents in a uniform random permutation are one-dependent. They are also determinantal (as nonnegative integer valued random variables). In fact, all one-dependent processes are determinantal as proved in this article  https://arxiv.org/pdf/0904.3740.pdf which is

```
    On adding a list of numbers (and other one-dependent determinantal processes)
```

by Borodin, Diaconis and Fulman, published in *Bull. Amer. Math. Soc.*, 2010.
If you look at that article, the main section pertaining to your questions is
example 11 on page 12 which is descents in a uniform random permutation. They also give references to the original discoverer and main expositors: MacMahon; Stanley; and Gessel and Viennot.

The claim you are asking about is that $\mathbf{E}[W_n^4] \leq c n^2$ for some $c$. Then you can take $C = 144 c^2$ in your desired inequality. Let $\mathsf{X}_i$ be the indicator that the pair of spots $(i,i+1)$ give a descent in your permutation, for $i \in \{1,\dots,n-1\}$. Let $\mathsf{Y}_i = \mathsf{X}_i - \frac{1}{2}$, since $\mathbf{E}[\mathsf{X_i}]=1/2$. (If you write a permutation in 1-line notation, and then do a left-right reversal of the numbers you will interchange the set of descents with its complement, so all the $\mathsf{X}_i$'s are equally likely to be $0$ or $1$ if you just focus on their separate marginals.) Then $\mathsf{X}_i$ is independent of $\mathsf{X}_j$ for $|i-j|>1$. That is what it means to be 1-dependent. So $\mathsf{Y}_i$ is independent of $\mathsf{Y}_j$ for $|i-j|>1$. Therefore, in the quadruple sum
$$
\mathbf{E}[W_n^4]\, =\, \sum_{i,j,k,\ell=1}^{n-1} \mathbf{E}[\mathsf{Y}_i
\mathsf{Y}_j
\mathsf{Y}_k
\mathsf{Y}_\ell]
$$
you only need to keep those indices such that $|i-j|\leq 1$ and $|k-\ell|\leq 1$
and then consider what happens when you permute the components of the ordered 4-tuple $(i,j,k,\ell)$. Note that combinatorial factor is at most $4!=24$ and so for the purpose of just checking that there is a $c$, we could skip it at first. The reason we only need those cases is if some $Y_k$, for example satisfies that $\min(\{|k-i|,|k-j|,|k-\ell|\})$ were at least 2, then that variable would be independent of the other so we could move it into its own expectation. But $\mathbf{E}[\mathsf{Y}_k]=0$ since we centered it.

But then you are done. It is easy to see that the number of indices $(i,j,k,\ell)$
such that $|i-j|\leq 1$ and $|k-\ell| \leq 1$ is bounded by $3(n-1)$ times $3(n-1)$. That product is bounded by $cn^2$.